# Doctrine setting entity id at a later time

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an application in which I would like to edit already-existing entities, but all changes should only be made once the user explicitly clicks on "Save". So while he is editing nothing happens to the original.

Usually, that wouldn't be any problem, but since I'm saving changes over Ajax and not Symfony, I need to have that work-around.

It's working perfectly fine except for the part where it's supposed to write the id of the original entity into the edited one (the original gets removed when saving the changes).

At first I thought I'd copy all of the fields from the edited entity over into the original, but it's likely that, once fields are added, nobody will tell the application to also copy those fields over.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$editedEntity->setId($originalEntity->getId());

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->remove($originalEntity);
$em->flush();
```

Tl;dr

How can I copy the id of an entity into a different one?

Comment: ......... why would you, instead of actually editing the entity ... want to create a new entity with the same id (and probably lots of identical values)? I seriously don't get what people are doing nowadays ...

Comment: @Jakumi As I explained in the question, I want to be able to cancel editing, and that means that none of the changes are applied. But if I edit the actual entity then this won't be possible. From a performance point of view, I see your point, but I doubt it will be a serious concern for this particular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the id, remove and flush the old one then set id stored to your new entity.

```
$originalEntityId = $originalEntity->getId();

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->remove($originalEntity);
$em->flush();

$editedEntity->setId($originalEntityId);
$em->flush();
```